# how to find given date is falling in between two dates using apex

Tags: apex, custom

I have a requirement where i have to enter some date for example 12-15-2014 and there is already start date (11-01-2014) and end date (12-31-2014) in system. So, i have to find whether user entered date (12-15-2014) is falling in between start date and end date or not. How can i achieve this functionality using apex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I guess same way as any language, compare them ;)

something like

```
Date startDate = *start date*; Date endDate = *end date*; Date userDate = *user date*;

if(userDate > startDate     &&  userDate  < endDate ){   // do something }
```

But I still have feeling you question wasn't specific enought...